# Is there a way to undifference a fractionally differenced time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, differencing, arfima

Say I have data

```
d <- .4

series <- 100-0:6

fd_data <-  diffseries(series, d)
```

fd_data:

```
3.000000  0.800000 -0.160000 -0.832000 -1.372800 -1.837056 -2.250394
```

[How] Is it possible to get back to the original values?

Comment: This looks useful possibly. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404475/fractional-un-differencing-of-time-series

Comment: I saw that.  That is standard arima, not arfima from what I can tell.

Comment: Hi: Yeah. Sorry. I just went by the title which I guess is wrong.